# Can anyone explain why the output of True, True == (True, True) is (True, False)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to do a comparison like the code below with Python, but instead was confused by the output produced.

Can anyone explain why the output is like this?

```
>>> True, True == True, True
(True, True, True)
>>> True, True == (True, True)
(True, False)
```

Comment: Because the first one is `True, (True == True), True` and the second is `True, (True == (True, True))`. I think you wanted `(True, True) == (True, True)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe no matter the language, knowing your operator precedence is vital!

Comment: @MarkRansom it's very helpful! The comma isn't strictly an operator, this is covered in https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-s-up-with-the-comma-operator-s-precedence.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck... but I get what you're saying.  Thanks for the additional detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of operator precedence. `==` has higher precedence than `,`, so the first expression is treated as if you'd written

```
True, (True == True), True
```

Your second expression is treated as

```
True, (True == (True, True))
```

If you want to compare the two sides of `==` element-wise, you need to parenthesize both sides:

```
(True, True) == (True, True)
```

This will return `True`.

Note that comma is [not strictly an operator](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-s-up-with-the-comma-operator-s-precedence), so but for the purposes of understanding this behavior it's close enough.